# Python Server doesn't load image

Tags: python

I have a web server in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

def onoff(pin, on_off):
        GPIO.output(pin, on_off)
        return

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        params = {}

        def do_GET(self):

                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                self.end_headers()

                if self.path.startswith("/favicon.ico"):
                        return
                elif self.path=="/":
                        f = open(curdir + sep + "/index.html")
                        self.wfile.write(f.read())
                        f.close()
                elif self.path.startswith("/remote.html"):

                        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

                        self.params = {}

                        if self.path.find("?") > -1:
                                p = self.path.split("?")[-1]
                                p = p.split("&")

                                for v in p:
                                        pair = v.split("=")
                                        self.params[pair[0]] = pair[1]


                        led = int(self.querystring("led"))
                        GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

                        if self.querystring("action") == "on":
                                onoff(led, GPIO.HIGH)
                        elif self.querystring("action") == "off":
                                onoff(led, GPIO.LOW)

                        self.wfile.write("Led " + str(led))

                return

        def querystring(self, key):

                return self.params[key]

try:

        GPIO.cleanup()
        server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
        print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

        server.serve_forever()
        GPIO.cleanup()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
```

But I'm unable to load an image for the  tag in the index.html page, how could I do?

Comment: You're simple server isn't programmed to serve images; it's only programmed to serve `index.html` and `remote.html`.

Comment: I know this, but i want to say how can i program the server to serve the image? And in the html page what i have to specify on the attribute src of the img tag?

Comment: So, add yet another `elif` similar to what you have for `index.html` and put the image into the same folder as `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You may add another "elif":

```
# ...
elif self.path == "/yourimage.jpeg":
    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.end_headers()
    with open("yourimage.jpg", "rb") as fout:
        self.wfile.write(fout.read())
# ...
```

Move this three lines...

```
self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
self.end_headers()
```

This is due to the 
To each already existent if's, except for the new one

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
from os import curdir, sep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

PORT_NUMBER = 8080

def onoff(pin, on_off):
    GPIO.output(pin, on_off)
    return

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    params = {}

    def do_GET(self):

        self.send_response(200)

        if self.path.startswith("/favicon.ico"):
            return
        elif self.path=="/":
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            self.end_headers()
            f = open(curdir + sep + "/index.html")
            self.wfile.write(f.read())
            f.close()
        elif self.path.startswith("/remote.html"):
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            self.end_headers()
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

            self.params = {}

            if self.path.find("?") > -1:
                p = self.path.split("?")[-1]
                p = p.split("&")

                for v in p:
                    pair = v.split("=")
                    self.params[pair[0]] = pair[1]

           led = int(self.querystring("led"))
           GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

           if self.querystring("action") == "on":
               onoff(led, GPIO.HIGH)
           elif self.querystring("action") == "off":
               onoff(led, GPIO.LOW)

           self.wfile.write("Led " + str(led))

       elif self.path == "/yourimage.jpeg":
           self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
           self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           self.end_headers()
           with open("yourimage.jpg", "rb") as fout:
               self.wfile.write(fout.read())
       return

    def querystring(self, key):
        return self.params[key]

try:

    GPIO.cleanup()
    server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
    print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

    server.serve_forever()
    GPIO.cleanup()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
```

Comment: And change self.send_header('Content-type','text/html') to "image/jpeg" as well

Comment: And from te html page i can write <img src="/image.png">